# Equivalent in C# to Haskell's Data.List.Span

Tags: c#, linq, haskell

Hello is there any efficient method implemented already to get the functionality of Haskell `Data.List.span`?

```
span :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
```

Basically given a `list` and a `predicate` i want to split the list in two after **the first** occurence of a false predicate.The elements after the `pivot` element that tests `False` may or may not respect the predicate , but I do not care.

```
List: [1,2,3,1,2,3]
Predicate: x<3
Span:  `span  (x<3) [1,2,3,1,2,3]`   =>  `([1,2],[3,1,2,3])`
```

**Update**
I do not care of the elements after the first false predicate.I just want to split the list at the first occurence of `False` predicate. The sequence can be `True` after the first `False` predicate but I still want to split it.

Comment: Just to clarify: You are looking for a method that takes a List<T> and a Func<T, bool> as input and returns a Tuple<List<T>, List<T>>?

Comment: How would `[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]` be split? To `[1, 2]`, `[3, 4, 3, 2, 1]` ?

Comment: Yes,  i have updated my post.I want the list to break at the first occurence of a false predicate.The elements after the pivot may or may not test true.It does not matter.

Comment: And do you want two new lists, or (if it's more efficient) do you want one part in the original list (truncated accordingly) and the other part in a new list? And finally, can you use .Net Core 3?

Comment: I do not want necessary lists.I want two enumerables .The first being the elements spanning before the first false predicate , and the second being the elements and including and after the one that failed the predicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are happy with using lists, then you can make a single pass through the source list to create two new lists, like so:

```
public static (List<T> part1, List<T> part2) SplitListBy<T>(List<T> source, Predicate<T> splitWhen)
{
    var part1 = new List<T>();

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < source.Count && !splitWhen(source[i]); ++i)
        part1.Add(source[i]);

    var part2 = source.GetRange(i, source.Count - i);

    return (part1, part2);
}
```

This should be extremely performant. Note that this uses a tuple to return the two lists, which requires C# 7 or later. If you can't use c# 7+, you'll have to change the code to use an `out` parameter to return one of the lists.

Test code:

```
var list = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 };

var (part1, part2) = SplitListBy(list, item => item >= 3);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", part1));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", part2));
```

Output:

```
1, 2
3, 1, 2, 3
```

---

If you don't need two new lists, but just want to use the original list for one part and a single new list for the other part, you can do it like this:

```
public static List<T> SplitListBy<T>(List<T> source, Predicate<T> splitWhen)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < source.Count && !splitWhen(source[i]); ++i)
        ;

    var part2 = source.GetRange(i, source.Count - i);

    source.RemoveRange(i, source.Count - i);

    return part2;
}
```

Test code for this is very similar:

```
var list = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 };

var part2 = SplitListBy(list, item => item >= 3);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", part2));
```

(Output is the same as the other test code.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.This looks like it's  what  i needed , doing it one iteration,  though i was hoping there is something out of box (`Linq` toolbox :D ).

Comment: I am using `C#8` , there's no issue with the tuple.

Comment: Technically, tuples have been available since .NET 4.0 released alongside of C# 4.0, but they had to be explicit. So you would have to replace `(List<T> list1, List<T> list2)` with `Tuple<List<T>, List<T>>` and it would work with C# 4.0, no need for 7+. What you are using is [tuple constructing/ deconstructiing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct) which you correctly stated to only be available in C# 7.0 and newer

Answer (score 3):

You could make use of `TakeWhile` and `Skip`:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitWhen<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    var first = enumerable.TakeWhile(predicate);
    yield return first;
    var second = enumerable.Skip(first.Count());
    yield return second;
}
```

---

**Update**

To avoid multiple iterations, and not requiring the use of a list or array:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitWhen<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    yield return enumerable.TakeWhile(predicate);
    yield return enumerable.TakeAfter(predicate);
}

public static IEnumerable<T> TakeAfter<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    bool yielding = false;
    foreach (T item in enumerable)
    {
        if (yielding = yielding || !predicate(item))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `first.Count() `

Comment: @styx Yes, well spotted.

Comment: Just a heads up: You are enumerating over `enumerable` and `first` multiple times

Comment: Yes that is what i want to avoid.I do not want to iterate multiple times over the initial enumerable.

Answer (score 2):

At the time that I'm writing this answer, I don't think that any of the other answers faithfully replicate Haskell's `span` function. That's okay, you may actually be looking for something else, but I wanted to add this for completion's sake.

First, you can't necessarily assume that `span` only iterates over the input list once. It's difficult to reason about Haskell's run-time behaviour because of its lazy evaluation, but consider this list:

```
xs = [trace "one" 1, trace "two" 2, trace "three" 3,
      trace "one" 1, trace "two" 2, trace "three" 3]
```

Here I've deliberately used `trace` from `Debug.Trace` so that we can observe what's going on. Specifically, I want to point your attention to what happens if you iterate over the lists independently, as one would probably do in 'real' code:

```
Prelude Data.List Debug.Trace> (l, r) = span (< 3) xs
Prelude Data.List Debug.Trace> l
one
[1two
,2three
]
```

Iterating over the first list stops at the first value that evaluates to `False`, so that's fine and efficient. That's not the case, however, when you print the second list:

```
Prelude Data.List Debug.Trace> r
one
two
three
[3,one
1,two
2,three
3]
```

Notice that while it only *prints* `[3, 1, 2, 3]`, it iterates over the entire list. How could it do otherwise? It's a function. It doesn't maintain a bookmark over how far it's already iterated the list.

On the other hand, the function *does* handle infinite lists:

```
Prelude Data.List> take 10 $ fst $ span (< 3) $ repeat 1
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
Prelude Data.List> take 10 $ fst $ span (< 3) $ repeat 3
[]
Prelude Data.List> take 10 $ snd $ span (< 3) $ repeat 3
[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
```

As far as I can tell, few of the other answers (as I'm writing this) handle infinite lists.

In C#, lazily evaluated lists are modelled with `IEnumerable<T>`, so the best I've been able to come up with is this:

```
public static (IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>) Span<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, bool> pred)
{
    return (source.TakeWhile(pred), source.SkipWhile(pred));
}
```

which, admittedly, is hardly above the [Fairbairn threshold](https://wiki.haskell.org/Fairbairn_threshold). It does, however, handle infinite sequences in the same way as `span` does:

```
> var (left, right) = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 }.Span(x => x < 3);
> left
TakeWhileIterator { 1, 2 }
> right
SkipWhileIterator { 3, 1, 2, 3 }
> var (left, right) = 1.RepeatInfinite().Span(x => x < 3);
> left.Take(10)
TakeIterator { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
> var (left, right) = 3.RepeatInfinite().Span(x => x < 3);
> right.Take(10)
TakeIterator { 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 }
> left.Take(10)
TakeIterator { }
```

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way to use [ToLookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup?view=netframework-4.8)

**example**

```
var listInt = new List<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
var result = listInt.ToLookup(x => x > 3);
```

**Result**

[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]

**Edit**

```
var listInt = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 };
```

Create an extension method

```
        public static IEnumerable<T> TakeUntil<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
        {
            foreach (var item in source)
            {
                if (!predicate(item))
                    break;
                yield return item;
            }
        }
```

and call it

```
var first = listInt.TakeUntil(x => x < 3);
var second = listInt.Skip(first.Count());
```

**Result**

first = [1,2]

second = [3, 1, 2, 3]

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian why not use a simple for loop?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a native .NET Framework or .NET Core method that does this, so you'll probably have to write your own. Here is my extension method implementation of this:

```cs
public static Tuple<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>> SplitWhen<T>(this IEnumerable<T> self, Func<T, bool> func)
{
    // Enumerate self to an array so we don't do it multiple times
    var enumerable = self as T[] ?? self.ToArray();
    var matching = enumerable.TakeWhile(func).ToArray();
    var notMatching = enumerable.Skip(matching.Length);

    return new Tuple<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>>(matching, notMatching);
}
```

This method will return a tuple with `tuple.Item1` being the part of the list that matches the predicate, and `tuple.Item2` being the rest of the list.

This method needs to be declared in a separate static class as it is an extension method for `IEnumerable<T>`. You can also use [Tuple construction/ deconstruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct) if you want to name `Item1` and `Item2` something different

Comment: This also iterates over the collection more than once. It also doesn't support deferred execution, and can potentially use lots of memory by creating an array. Is this really worth it just to make the count `O(1)` rather than `O(n)`?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay the difference between this and yours is that I'm enumerating over the `IEnumerable` once, meaning I'm only executing every piece of code on the enumerable once. Said code can be short, or none at all, but may also be a large and complex LINQ statement that can take relatively long to execute. Yes it does use more memory and does not support deferred execution but it is baseline faster and can be a lot faster depending on the input

Comment: I get your point with the potentially complex `IEnumerable` logic, but surely this is the responsibility of the caller. You don't see any of the LINQ methods using arrays or anything else that requires the collection to be stored in memory; they all have deferred execution and are memory efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a c# IEnumerable. You could write for example

```
IEnumerable<int> list = new List<int> { 1,2,3,4,5,6};
var list1 = list.Where(x=>x>3); //deferred execution
var list2 = list.Where(x=>x<=3); //deferred execution
```

Comment: an IEnumrable is not exactly a list, it's not exactly an array, nor is it a graph... It's all of them and none. It's an interface, for deferred looping.

Comment: The problem is that i need to break the list in two when the predicate hits.I can not test more times.It has to be in one go.I take items as long as the predicate is true, then the rest of the list might or might not conform to the predicate.I might have [1,2,3,1,2,3]. In this case i want to split on the predicate `>3` and get `([1,2],[3,1,2,3])`

Comment: yes, but the Where statement gives you such a lovely deferred execution in o(1). Why not take advantage of the IEnumerable syntax? You are by no means running over the entire array with this. Even if you array is a million items long, stating a WHERE on it will take less that a second;

Answer (score 0):

I have accepted  @Matthew Watson solution.Though i will also post a little modified version  using the `Span` and `ReadOnlyMemory`

```
public static (IEnumerable<T>first,IEnumerable<T> second) Span<T>(this ReadOnlyMemory<T> original,Func<T,bool> predicate) {
            List<T> list = new List<T>();

            int splitIndex = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < original.Length && !predicate(original.Span[i]); i++) {
                list.Add(original.Span[splitIndex=i]);
            }
            var part2 = original.Slice(splitIndex);
            return (list, part2.ToArray());
        }
```